# Getting 'bad substitution' error in Yocto shell code

Tags: yocto, bitbake, datastore

I have following shell code in my recipe

```
VARIABLE_dev = "dev value"
VARIABLE_prod = "prod value"

do_compile() {
    variant="dev"
    echo ${VARIABLE_${variant}}
}
```

As a result I alway get 'bad substitution' error

```
/home/dev/testproj/tmp/work/machine-poky-linux-gnueabi/test-app/1.0-raspberrypi-r0/temp/run.do_compile.253: 121: Bad substitution
```

If the 'variant' variable is defined as datastore variable (outside shell code scope) then it works fine. But in the code I pasted I always get error.
Any idea what could be the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

The conditional variable expansion syntax that you are using requires `OVERRIDES` variable, you can check details [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0.4/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#conditional-syntax-overrides).

But the example you provided is not correct and cannot be used.

The principle of OVERRIDES is just when you want to override a variable condionally based on some key.

But, I will suggest something more suitable for your case, which is `Variable Flags`.

Here is an example:

```
VARIABLE[dev] = "dev value"
VARIABLE[prod] = "prod value"
```

Now if you use a Shell based task you can use Python expansion:

```
do_compile(){
   bbwarn ${@d.getVarFlags("VARIABLE").get('dev')}
}
```

This should show a warning with the value "dev value"

You can then make it more conditional using another variable, for example:

```
PROJECT_TYPE = "dev"

do_compile(){
   bbwarn ${@d.getVarFlags("VARIABLE").get(d.getVar('PROJECT_TYPE'))}
}
```

You can use a python task directly for more flexible python syntax.

**Advice**: use `logging.bbclass` utilities to make the log:

**Shell**: bbinfo, bbwarn, bberror, ...

**Python**: bb.info, bb.warn, bb.error, ...

Update:
Loop through the flags with shell for loop:

```
flags="${@''.join(' ' + flag for flag, _ in d.getVarFlags('PACKAGECONFIG').items())}"
for flag in $flags; do
   bbwarn "$flag"
done
```

Comment: I like method you presented but still it does not fit my needs.
I'd like to reference PROJECT_TYPE condition variable as shell variable and not datastore, for instance:
    `for project_type in "dev prod"; do
        bbwarn ${@d.getVarFlags("VARIABLE").get(${project_type})}
    done`
How can I make this example working?

Comment: I did manage to loop through the flags with shell for loop, but I didn't manage to get the value of a flag from a python call using a shell variable. See my update.